# gulp imagimine plugin throwinf error while optimizing images

Tags: docker, gulp

I have such a gulp task

```
gulp.task('images', () => {
  return gulp.src('assets/images/**/*')
      .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/images'));
});
```

and it throwing error in this line `.pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))` for me:

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write callback called multiple times
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/var/www/vhosts/devgenix/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:84:31)
    at EventEmitter.signals.on.err (/var/www/vhosts/devgenix/node_modules/gulp-cache/lib/index.js:451:7)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.onError (/var/www/vhosts/devgenix/node_modules/gulp-cache/lib/index.js:288:15)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/devgenix/node_modules/through2-concurrent/through2-concurrent.js:37:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

but for other developers on their machines, all works fine.

I'm running all the code under the custom alpine docker container with preinstalled node (other devs no), so maybe it's an issue and I just need to install some missing dependency but I can't figure out what is wrong.

My docker file is actually for PHP with the node, here is the docker file content:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

ENV ZMQ_VERSION 4.3.1

ENV BUILD_DEPS autoconf file gcc libc-dev make g++ pkgconf re2c git

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $BUILD_DEPS

# Error code: 127
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .php-build-deps \
 nasm \
        libsodium \
        freetype-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        postgresql-dev  \
        libxml2-dev  \
        zlib-dev cyrus-sasl-dev libmemcached-dev   \

        # the next line is for node and npm packages (node-sass requires python/make/g++ to build something)

        python \
        && apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm \
        # for GD
        bash \
        freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev \

        # just good to have installed
        ca-certificates wget \

        ## Install git (we'll never delete it)
        #&& apk add --no-cache git \

        && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
            --with-gd \
            --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
            --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
            --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \

        && NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) \

        ## Installable modules
        && docker-php-ext-install -j${NPROC} iconv mcrypt bcmath pdo_mysql opcache pgsql pdo_pgsql soap pcntl exif zip gd \
        && apk del --no-cache freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev \

        ## Memcached
        && git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached.git \
        && cd php-memcached \
        && git checkout php7 \
        && phpize \
        && ./configure --disable-memcached-sasl \
        && make \
        && cp modules/memcached.so $(php-config --extension-dir) \
        && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \


        ## Composer
        && cd ~ \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \

        ## Gulp
        && npm install -g gulp \

        ## Cleanup
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure calendar && docker-php-ext-install calendar

ADD www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d
ADD php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

WORKDIR /var/www/vhosts/devgenix/

#EXPOSE 22

CMD ["php-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf"]
```

Maybe someone has any ideas why it's not working for me? Thanks!

**updated**

npm version: 6.4.1
gulp version: 3.9.1
gulp-imagemin version: 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by adding `libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng libpng-dev automake` dependencies to my docker file